# Doubly linked list insertion after/before node

Tags: doubly-linked-list

For most online examples I found for insertion in doubly linked lists, the common motive is to define a node structure or class with *next,*prev and data and then to define the List class with usually those insertion options:

InsertFront(data)

InsertBack(data)

InsertAfter(*node,data)

InsertBefore(*node,data)

For the last two methods, inserting before or after a node, it is supposed that you have a node at hand. 
My question is where do you get that node from, in a regular working sequence? Why the Clist user has to know what an internal node is, and if I make the node for instance an internal private class or struct in CList, then why should I have to pass it in order to insert after/before?

I know that I can alternatively use 
AddAfter(int pos,data) 
To add at a specific position, but this will require traversing the list until I reach that position index?

Comment: I can't imagine the 2 methods which required *node are intended as a public interface.  Perhaps they are utilized for recursion or something but they would only be of use as private methods.

Comment: Thanks, but it is logical to have it as public because as far as I can see that is the edge a list has over an array - if you have a node and want to add a value after that node, you don't have to travel all over the list - you just use the *next,*prev pointers of that node to add a new node after/before it. Which means that way you have O(1) for adding / deletion.
For instance, in wiki it is part of public interface:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list

Comment: I guess my question in other words Is:
Can you achieve O(1) for inserting/deleting (which is what a list should provide) without having to provide a node for the insert/delete?

Comment: So, probably my assumption is wrong and O(1) can be achieved only if I have the node, otherwise I must traverse the list to O(n) in worst case. Still, it's not that clear to me in what scenarios I might have the node in order to get O(1).